# Ubuntu Desktop Problem - Org.gtk.vfs.Daemon Error

Tags: unity, wine

I installed standard Ubuntu 14.04 LTS about a fortnight ago and everything has been working fine. Yesterday I installed Wine via the standard package manager and then installed a simple windows exe WBridge5 (using wine) and then ran it a couple of times using wine and all was fine. Note that this may be irrelevant.

Today I started my DELL Inspiron 6400 and after entering my password the standard desktop appeared without my previously set background; the file mgr appears automatically (without the recent files icon) and the following message appears:

> "Oops! Something went wrong. 
>   Unhandled error message: The name org.gtk.vfs.Daemon was not provided by any .Service files."

After acknowledging the message, my programs operate but **WITHOUT** a text menu showing on the top menu bar. There are other minor inconveniences such as Alt+Tab doesn't work and there is no "Recent" option on the Files program and "System Settings Appearance" cannot be changed. The show stopper for me is that unless a program has a non text menu method of running a menu option, you are stuffed. This affects Libreoffice really badly.

I have searched the web for the error message above and tried various remedies, including uninstalling wine and removing ubuntu-desktop and reinstalling it using dpkg. No success or change to desktop behaviour.

> sudo apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop
>   sudo apt-get install --reinstall unity

Now logged as an Ubuntu bug. See:

> https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1548841

Following the following actions, the bug is now largely fixed but a few problems remain. (see below)

I removed and reinstalled the unity, compiz and then gconf packages e.g.

> sudo apt-get purge unity
>   sudo rm /usr/share/dbus-1/services

The package removal process was not simple as there were lots of problems including the usual messages about dependencies and a number of messages about not being able to remove /usr/share/dbus-1/services files.

The situation now is that the window text menus now appear and Alt+Tab switches between windows.

Not quite clear what has fixed this - was it the reinstall or the removal of the dbus-1 directory. The following problems still exist:

- Changes to System Settings Appearance don't save and existing ones
  take no effect, e.g. bland system background displays.
- Unable to start the Terminal app. Ctrl+T does nothing. Ctrl+Alt+F1   continues to work fine.
- The org.gtk.vfs message still appears at session start up.
- Rubbish Bin AND Browse Network are NOT working on the Files app and the org.gtk.vfs message displays.
- Ubuntu Software Center does not start.

Comment: The message is that *systemd* .service files didn't provide the service. Interestingly, I didn't find any ubuntu package that would provide a `…vfs….service` file. But just a blind guess: try to open a terminal *(since you have problems, you can just switch between a terminal and graphical sessions with «Ctrl+Alt+F1/F7»)*, and try to enter `sudo service gvfsd start` and `sudo systemctl start gvfsd`. If they both would print errors about a missing service, try to run it manually `/usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd`. Ah, I think you have to try it before you entered the password to enter the graphical session.

Comment: Many thanks @Hi-Angel, when I run   /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd I get the following error: "Failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon: cannot auto launch D-BUS without X11 $DISPLAY (g-io-error-quark, 0)".  Then no change to the desktop behaviour. Regards.............. Peter.

Comment: Okay, then try to run it like `DISPLAY=":0" /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd`. First try it before you entered password to open the graphical session; if it would spit out the same error, then enter the graphical session, and try again.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, when I run "DISPLAY=:0" /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd before password entry I get the following error

Failed to connect to the D-Bus Daemon: Error spawning command line 
"dbus-launch --autolaunch=335d1470...... --binary-sytax --close-stderr" Child process exited with code 1 (g-spawn-exit-error-quark,1)

When I do the same after entering my password and the faulty desktop appears, I do not get the error but there does not seem to be any change to the desktop misbehaviour.

Thanks............. Peter.

Comment: What DE are you using? Are you using `unity`? If so, try to do next: Ⅰ) open graphical session, Ⅱ) enter in the «Ctrl+Alt+F1» terminal `DISPLAY=":0" /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd &`, Ⅲ) enter `DISPLAY=":0" sudo unity --replace` Ⅳ) check whether it worked or spew more errors. **UPD:** ah, if you would see something like "Unity is already running", try `killall unity`, and the command `DISPLAY=":0" unity --replace` again. **UPD2:** sorry, I just noticed the tag Kubuntu, so you have to run all the same commands, but replace `unity` with `kwin`.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, 
Not sure what desktop I am using. $DESKTOP_SESSION empty. Terminal can't find kwin. 

After  unity --replace, Desktop dies,  pwd prompt appears and restricted desktop appears again.

Terminal shows 20 lines including

dconf-warning  Failed to commit changes to dconf  Error spawning command line......

compiz core - Unity is not supported by your hardware. Rendering software rendering instead (slow)
compiz core -Starting plugin opengl
XIO - fatal error 11 (resource Temporarily unavailable) on X server 
after 1671 requests with 155 events remaining

Many thanks............. Peter.

Comment: I see the complains are from compiz, it's another WM. You could then try all the same commands I mentioned, but with `compiz`, like `compiz --replace`. By the way, on the login screen *(where you usually entering a password)*, is there a choice between other sessions? Are the other sessions work?

Comment: @Hi-Angel, am currently running compiz --replace. It seems to be hung after displaying messages about compizconfig info  including Backend-ini, integration-true and currently Profile-default. Has been sitting there for 10 minutes saying nothing. Will leave for a while and reboot and try again? Thanks....... Peter. PS> unable to chat.

Comment: The question is, does the `compiz --replace` fixed the problem in the graphical session, or not? Also, did you try to login into other sessions on the login screen *(if there any)*? There should be a dropdown list with session types. Something like «Gnome», «Gnome fallback», etc.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, unfortunately the problem is not fixed. The compiz --replace continues to hang and unity --replace crashes as before.  Re the login screen, the only options I have are to choose to sign on as guest or myself. No options of a different shell. There is Ubuntu 14.04 LTS decal bottom left and a menu bar at the top with network, battery, sound, time and closedown icons. Thanks........ Peter.

Comment: Compiz didn't hang — it is Window Manager, it is supposed to start once, and work until you log out from graphical session *(either until you manually kill it, like pressing «Ctrl+c» in the terminal where you started it)*. Login into graphical session, then switch to terminal, enter `DISPLAY=":0" /usr/lib/gvfs/gvfsd &`, then enter `DISPLAY=":0" compiz --replace`, switch back to graphical session, and check if anything changed.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, unfortunately things actually get worse when the compiz --replace command  is running. The side program menu bar, the top screen menu  and the window menu all disappear. Ow. In fact I need to power off my machine to exit.  Sorry and thanks ........ Peter.

Comment: Okay, then let's return to errors that `unity --replace` did output previously. Try to do that: before you login into graphical session, execute in the «Ctrl+Alt+F1» terminal `mv ~/.config ~/.configBCKP`, then finally login into graphical session, and see if anything changed.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, doesn't seem to make much difference except losing a few setup things. I still get the message and no menus. After testing I have put my original .config back in place. Regards............... Peter.

Comment: Yeah, that's getting hard… Okay, could you then show the content of the `/var/log/syslog` file after you logged in graphical session?

Comment: @Hi-Angel

I put the system log in the main topic text yesterday. I don't know if you saw it.  I think that dconf is not starting/operating correctly for me. Maybe its corrupted. I am unable to install lumbuntu and gnome-session because I get dconf problems. I am also not able to amend anything with the gconf tool.

conftool GconfWARNING Client failed to connect to the D-BUS daemon

The message when I start unity seems to be about gvfs, see :
wiki.gnome.org/Projects/gvfs/doc

No idea where to go next. I will probably raise a Unity bug if we don't solve the problem soon.
Thanks........ Peter.

Comment: Yeah, I didn't see that. Sorry, I took a look at the log, and have completely no idea what to do further, my eyes couldn't catch hints of what could happened. Interestingly, your question have too much views — assuming that the question felt down under other questions long ago, it seems that you're not alone with that problem…

Comment: @Hi-Angel, many thanks. As indicated, I have now raised an ubuntu bug. See
>https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gvfs/+bug/1548841
Many thanks....... Peter.

Comment: @Hi-Angel, menu issue resolved. See main text. Thanks for all your help. Peter.